# How to get different data from gridview

Tags: php, yii, yii2

I want to show different record from my gridview when I click to gridview item. Now when I clicked to item I have this url:
http://localhost/test/basic/site/0

I'm add actionView to my controller to handle that but dont know what to do in it. In my gridview records number start for 0, but in db I have only 3,4,5 records. How I can handle this?
My method in controller:

```
public function actionIndex()
    {
        if(Yii::$app->user->isGuest)
        {
            return $this->redirect(['login']);
        }
        else
        {
        $dataProvider = new SqlDataProvider([
    'sql' => 'SELECT p.id,p.user_id,p.post_title,p.post_text,u.name ' .
             'FROM Posts p '.
             'INNER JOIN User u ' .
             'ON p.user_id = u.id'
]);
        return $this->render('index',['dataProvider'=>$dataProvider]);
        }
    }
```

in actionIndex I show index page with all records from my db.
and I have another method what must to handle click for item. Now it's just do same like actionIndex.

```
public function actionView($id)
   {
       if(Yii::$app->user->isGuest)
       {
           return $this->redirect(['login']);
       }
       else
       {
       $dataProvider = new SqlDataProvider([
   'sql' => 'SELECT p.id,p.user_id,p.post_title,p.post_text,u.name ' .
            'FROM Posts p '.
            'INNER JOIN User u ' .
            'ON p.user_id = u.id'
]);
       return $this->render('index',['dataProvider'=>$dataProvider]);
       }
    }
```

Comment: Is not clear what do you need .. with actionView ... you want view a form for the User  with id = 0 ?  ..  or you want a gridview with the list of you User .. like in you index.php  ? try explain better what you are trying to do ..

Comment: I'm want to show one record in another view when click for item in gridview

Comment: Well .. i have posted an answer  for this ..

Comment: U can use yii1 gii generator to generate basic CRUD operations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tipically an actionView is used for show the valaue related  to a  single instance

```
public function actionView($id)
{
   $model => User::findModel($id);

    return $this->render('view', [
        'model' => $model,
    ]);
}
```

and in views/your_controller/  view.php

```
<div class="my-model-view">

<h3>My Title</h3>


<?= DetailView::widget([
    'model' => $model,
    'attributes' => [
        'your_column1',
        'your_column1',
    ......  
    ],
]) ?>
```

where your_column1 ,.... are the name of your attribute in $model